# What exactly are Ayame and Shinya majoring in?

Tags: science-fell-in-love

I was not able to find on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science_Fell_in_Love,_So_I_Tried_to_Prove_It) or on the fandom ([Ayame Himuro](https://rikei.fandom.com/wiki/Ayame_Himuro), [Shinya Yukimura](https://rikei.fandom.com/wiki/Shinya_Yukimura)). The 1st episode doesn't quite say explicitly, but...

[image]

[image]

It says Ayame in particular however has a goal of winning the Fields Medal specifically, where according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fields_Medal)

> With the exception of two PhD holders in Physics (Edward Witten and Martin Hairer),[20] only people with a PhD in mathematics have won the medal.

This must mean that Ayame's major is almost definitely specifically in maths/applied maths/stats (unlikely theoretical maths) instead of something like physics, computer science, information science, etc, but I guess possibly mathematical physics, mathematical computer science (if there's such a thing), etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh they sorta say it in 2nd episode at 0:44. Their department is InfoSci: 'Information and Computer Science'. Still it doesn't exactly say their exact majors.

[image]